# Sublime Monokai Syntax Highlighting: How to color method calls and make the color different inside of interpolated strings

Tags: ruby, syntax, colors, sublimetext2, highlighting

For Sublime's Monokai theme with Ruby, how do you

1) color method calls

[image]

(ie how do you make "generate_key" a different color.

2) make the color different inside of interpolated strings.

[image]

ie how do you make the 'puts "this is inside. Halp!" a different color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your second question, include this in your color theme (more info [here](http://i.justrealized.com/2013/add-ruby-string-interpolation-highlighting-sublime/)):

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Embedded Ruby Source</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>string source.ruby.embedded.source</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#D01F1E</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Resuling in:

[image]

For the first question, you may try [this](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#/Solarized%20%28dark%29) excelent tool to find out the keyword for method calls.